# Google "We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again." .addToFolder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

This code used to run fine for over a year now. It's a simple convert to pdf then put it in a folder.

```
var pdf = model.getAs("application/pdf");
var file = DocsList.createFile(pdf).addToFolder(foldersave);
```

All of a sudden:

`We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again.`

Now on every run. Bombs on the 2nd line. Not 1st.

Comment: what happens when you seperate the file creation from the folder add?

Comment: I just had a problem with a jpg file that had a dash in the name  causing an error.  But it took hours of debugging, and just by chance I had used a jpg file without a dash in the name, and my code worked fine.  I'm wondering if the problem has something to do with the `pdf` variable.  If you use `Logger.log("pdf var: " + pdg)` in your code, then look at the `View, Logs` output, maybe that will tell you something.  You could also try it without chaining the `addToFolder` method.  Separate each step out to debug every action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with the new Sheets and creating PDF's. The bug is here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579